# What's the highest character level in Torchlight?

Tags: torchlight

I was googling quite a lot for this question, but I couldn't find an answer. But what is the highest reachable character level in Torchlight?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The highest level attainable without the use of mods, is: **100**.

With the use of mods, you can reach level **999** (Link to the mod:[LVL&SkillMod](http://forums.runicgames.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=4133))

Comment: Oh my, that means lots of playing! :-)